# Scroll to bottom of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with scrolling a div to **bottom** with jQuery.

**Div**

*HTML:*

```
<div id="chatbox"></div>
```

*CSS:*

```
    #chatbox {
    width:300px;
    height:400px;
    background:grey;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #045671;
}
```

when i use onclick -> $("#chatbox").scrollTop(9999) the scroll goes to bottom, the problem comes after clicking again the scroll goes +20px up.

EXAMPLE : `http://46.238.10.232:10001/chat/`

Comment: add your code to http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Clicking again!?!?  Elaborate.

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski after cliking submit button againe

Comment: @SVS here is a fast example to test 

http://46.238.10.232:10001/chat/

Comment: ...Like, there's no way an IP-address style URL will even leave my corporate LAN, let alone reach its Internet proxy servers.  Have you tried putting your example on the Web, rather than just on the Internet?  I.e. using some DNS perhaps, and maybe on a web port too?

Answer (score 2):

If you over-set [`scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollTop), magic happens (or doesn't, depending on your expectation).  Setting `scrollTop` to 9999 will set the `scrollTop` to any number between 0 and 9999, depending on necessity.  You can also *read* `scrollTop`, so setting it to `x` doesn't mean it will stay `x`, it will be the actual position, so that it still makes sense should you be interested in querying the value ever.

If the contents of the element change, you'll have to set `scrollTop` again.  Usually to [`scrollHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollHeight) will always be sufficient (yes you could try to calculate `scrollTop` perfectly accurately, but why bother?  Let the browser do the calculation, and get back to work).

So I guess, when you 'click again' (whatever that is), you're adding more content to your chatbox.  Yes?  Then you've got to set `scrollTop`, *again*!

---

If you **are** setting `scrollTop` every time, you're probably doing it too early.  You should do it after you've modified the element's content, rather than merely in response to an `onclick` event.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).scrollTop($("#chatbox").position.top+$("#chatbox").height());
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<a>` tag might do the trick. I know it is pretty ugly, but with css you can style it as normal text or hide it entirely.

1. Place a custom element where you want to scroll to.
2. Set it's id to (for example) `scrollelement`.
3. Set `window.location.hash` to 'scrollelement'.

Credits to Lee Kowalkowski.

Comment: Woah! You've not needed to use the `<a>` __element__ to do this for quite some time now (not since you were able to use the id attribute and not the name attribute).  Any element's ID can be referred to by a URI fragment identifier (`#`).  You can also browse to it without generating click events or additional `<a>` elements, just `window.location.hash = 'element-id'`.

Comment: Using the URI to scroll though will interfere with the user's browsing history, so you could inconvenience the back button this way.